# 'indexPath' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, didselectrowatindexpath, nsindexpath

I have the following error. **'indexPath' undeclared (first use in this function)**.

**Code**.
**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
cell.accessoryView = spinner;
[spinner startAnimating];
[spinner release];

[self performSelector:@selector(pushDetailView:) withObject:tableView afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

**pushDetailView**

```
- (void)pushDetailView:(UITableView *)tableView {

// Push the detail view here
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
//load the clicked cell.
DetailsImageCell *cell = (DetailsImageCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

//init the controller.
AlertsDetailsView *controller = nil;
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
controller = [[AlertsDetailsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsView_iPad" bundle:nil];
} else {
controller = [[AlertsDetailsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsView" bundle:nil];
}

//set the ID and call JSON in the controller.
[controller setID:[cell getID]];

//show the view.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

I think it's because I'm not parsing the indexPath value from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to `pushDetailView` but I don't know how to approach this.

Could someone please advise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you `pushDetailView:` method has no `indexPath` variable on it's scope.

Instead of

```
- (void)pushDetailView:(UITableView *)tableView {
```

You should make your method like this:

```
- (void)pushDetailView:(UITableView *)tableView andIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath {
```

and then `indexPath` would be declared on the method scope.

Then, inside your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, replace

```
[self performSelector:@selector(pushDetailView:) withObject:tableView afterDelay:0.1];
```

for the code bellow:

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self pushDetailView: tableView andIndexPath: indexPath];
});
```

This uses `GCD` to execute the code after a delay, instead of the `performSelector: withObject :afterDelay:` and here is [a nice post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205998/what-are-the-tradeoffs-between-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay-and-dispatc) explaining why sometimes is better to opt for this aproach

Comment: Cool... So I can use `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and `- (void)pushDetailView:(UITableView *)tableView andIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath` at the same time?

Comment: What do you mean by 'at the same time'?

Comment: Well... I edited the code explaining exactly what you should do... Let me know if you have any doubts :)

Comment: @Felipe: It's successfully pushing to the new view. Thanks. One problem though; when I go to the next view and go back again, the arrow on the cell I clicked disappears. Why? Also, there are 2 warnings though. First one is on:`[self pushDetailView: tableView andIndexPath: indexPath];`. -> **Method '-pushDetailView:andIndexPath.' not found (return type defaults to 'id')**. Second is: `- (void)pushDetailView:(UITableView *)tableView andIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath`. -> **'Alerts' may not respond to '-pushDetailView:andIndexPath'**. Do you know why? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess the arrow disappears because you replace it (in you accessoryView) by the `spinner` object. and the warning is probably because you haven't updated the method new signature into your .h file and then the compiler thinks this method may not exist

Comment: @Felipe: All's working now! I referenced the method in the .h file and fixed the arrow issue with `UIView *activityView = cell.accessoryView;`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to provide two arguments and perform after a delay package both arguments in an NSDictionary and pass it:

```
    NSDictionary *arguments = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    tableView, @"tableView", indexPath, @"indexPath", nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(pushDetailView:) withObject:arguments afterDelay:0.1];
    ...

- (void)pushDetailView:(NSDictionary *)arguments {
    UITableView *tableView = [arguments objectForKey:@"tableView"];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [arguments objectForKey:@"indexPath"];
    ...
```

Or as @Felipe suggests, use GCD.