# Delaying a method on a separate thread in objective C

Tags: objective-c, delay, nonblocking

Is there a way to delay a method call before it changes a key value in the user defaults?

For instance; I have method A which is an `IBAction` and Method B. If a key "keyOne" is false; method A sets "keyOne" to true via the `-[NSUserDefaults setBool: forKey:]` and then calls method B with an integer input of for time delay. Method B then needs to wait for whatever the delay was input to be in seconds and then change the "keyOne" back to true with the same NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)'s `dispatch_after()` to delay the operation. But, instead of using the main queue as generated by the Xcode code snippet, create your own queue, or utilize the background queue.

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.my.cool.new.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

double delayInSeconds = 10.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, myQueue, ^(void){

    // Reset stuff here (this happens on a non-main thead)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Make UI updates here. (UI updates must be done on the main thread)
    });
});
```

You can find more information on the difference between using `performSelector:` and `dispatch_after()` in the answer in this post: [What are the tradeoffs between performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: and dispatch_after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205998/what-are-the-tradeoffs-between-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay-and-dispat)

Comment: Thanks for the information on this; just what I had been looking for. Much appreciated!

Comment: Now if I add that to my UI and call my UI-updating methods there is still a delay.

Answer (score 3):

You can use perform selector from method A to call method B:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodName) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

If your method B needs to know the delay you can use withObject: to pass parameter, it needs to be NSNumber, not integer.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed; method B does not need to know the delay it just needs to happen. Thanks for this!

Comment: @Tukajo If you think this answer helped you, please mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Can't until after a certain time limit @Anindya Sengupta ;)

Comment: Grand Central Dispatch is the better route to go, so the other answer is probably the one you want to go with.