# Using dispatch_after in SpriteKit, passing multiple arguments from another class

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, grand-central-dispatch, skspritenode

I was using performSelector to generate SKSpriteNodes after a random period of time, until a lot of people told me it was better to use dispatch_after.

What I have understood is that I need to create a function that will have the dispatch_after and then there it will point to another function that I want to do repeatedly. But this creates a problem to me. I need to pass two arguments to the method that creates the SKSpriteNodes **from another class**.

If I've understood correctly, in that class I need to call the method that has the dispatch_after  so that it can perform the action repeatedly. Then, how would I do all of this? Do I need to pass those arguments multiple times? Also, I cannot addChild:the method that has the dispatch_after because it does not return a SKSpriteNode (the one that creates them does indeed). So, I'm really confused.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6206301/2043580

Comment: There are SKAction methods you can use for the same. Have a look at the **Creating Custom Actions** section on the Apple [reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: And I'm going to tell you that you shouldn't use dispatch_after either. ;)  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23978854/201863

Comment: @joseMaria you commented on the answer he linked ^^^ on July 7th. :/  Also, on your other question for this, I suggested you use `SKAction waitForDuration:withRange:` in combination with a `SKAction runBlock:` block to get a random delay.  Those suggesting `dispatch_after` are giving a more generic iOS based solution, which has significant caveats if using with SpriteKit. Please read the link above this comment again.