# Triggering a method after a delay without abusing [UIView animateWithDuration]?

Tags: objective-c, ios, timer, uiviewanimation

I have a UIViewController that should control 2 UIImageViews to fade in.

I managed to animate them using the UIView animateWithDuration method, like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
    animations:^{
      [mFrontpageTitle setAlpha:0];
      [mFrontpageTitle setAlpha:1];
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
      [self AnimatePause];
    }];
```

and

```
-(void)AnimatePause {
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
    animations:^{
      [mFrontpageTitle setAlpha:0.99];
      [mFrontpageTitle setAlpha:1];
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
      [self AnimateAuthor];
    }];
```

which fires the next animation. Now, creating a transition from .99 to 1.0 is not very clean.

Is there a better way to trigger a block or sending a message by just defining a duration?

thanks

Zuppa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSTimeInterval delay = 1.5; //in seconds
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];
```

Comment: Thanks. I have look into the completely wrong direction. I will see if this crashes if the UIView is being removed before the interval is complete.. :)

Comment: what if I want to call a method that takes two parameters?? like, for instance: `- (void) MoveSomethigFrom:(id)from To:(id)to;`

Comment: Either wrap your method in something that just takes one parameter (e.g. a dictionary with all the parameters), or use `dispatch_after` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4139331/573626) for an example).