# UICollectionView wrong contentSize on first load, correct after that

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a common UICollectionView with paging and all.

Still trying to figure out why on viewDidLoad:, viewWillAppear: and viewDidAppear: , only on first view call, I get the wrong size when calling myCollectionView.collectionView.contentSize.width. It always respond with 0 width (height is always correct). Successive reload of the view get me the correct one.

Resorted to using

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
```

which give me the correct width event on first load.

Still a mystery to me.

Comment: i'm sure it's something to do with autolayout.. try disabling it

Comment: Already disabled, first thing I thought too. It seems like it's not loading the view fast enough, because on reappearance the width is correct (for ex. when coming back to the same view).

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this problem?

Comment: Same problem here. Any comments?

Comment: Not yet, not tried on newer versions of iOS yet.

Comment: Stumbled upon a similar bug with different project on iOS 7. This time I get incorrect inset on first load after installing the app. All subsequent loading of the collection are correct. Can't find the right way to start finding a solution ...

Answer (score 74, accepted):

So I was seeing a similar issue where contentSize width was always zero.  The simple answer is...there is probably no content in the collectionView yet.  That was why it's content size is zero.

I was also noticing that sometimes after calling `invalidateLayout` on my UICollectionView, I was seeing that `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize`  was not the same as `self.collectionView.contentSize`.

After much searching I found a great hint [here in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230918/reloading-a-uicollectionview-using-reloaddata-method-returns-immediately-before)

What I needed to do to get both contentSize calculations to be the same was to call `[self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded]` immediately after calling `[self.collectionView reloadData]` or `[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]`.

This essentially forces the reload to happen immediately instead of on the next runloop cycle.

I really hope this solves your issue.

Comment: You saved my life. :D Thank you so so much. @ucangetit

Comment: I find my collectionView.contentSize.height is larger than the max result of `contentOffset.y`, even with `[self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded]`.

Comment: this didn't work for me. I'm using `layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)` and it returns 1, 1 even after calling self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded

Comment: @osrl make sure you set your `estimatedItemSize` close to your actual size of your cells.  This property is just a starting point for the system to size your cells with, if your cells are all wildly different sizes, then it's best to start with a size of your smallest cell IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was always getting content size zero. layoutIfNeeded() was not enough for me I have to get content size inside DispatchQueue.main.async ie

```
    self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print(self.collectionView.contentSize) 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same mistake ,and I resolve this by `layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MIN, 24)`, height 24 is which I wanted height, the item's  width is I want to auto calcullated