# What would be the equivalent of doing this with NSOperation?

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation, xcode4.5, nsoperationqueue

```
[self performSelector:@selector(stopPulling) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
```

The code is fine. I just think that using NSOperation and block should be the way to go for the future.

I am familiar with NSOperation. I just want to do the same thing with block and NSOperation.

I can do this with GCD already:

```
int64_t delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    <#code to be executed on the main queue after delay#>
});
```

C'mon. There is something that can be done in GCD that can't be done more easily in NSOperation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSOperationQueue does not provide a mechanism for delayed execution. Use GCD or NSTimer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making this:

```
#import "BGPerformDelayedBlock.h"

@implementation BGPerformDelayedBlock


+ (void)performDelayedBlock:(void (^)(void))block afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
{
    int64_t delta = (int64_t)(1.0e9 * delay);
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delta), dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
}

+(void)performSlightlyDelayedBlock:(void (^)(void))block
{
    [self performDelayedBlock:block afterDelay:.1];
}
@end
```

It's based on an answer in [How do you trigger a block after a delay, like -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139219/how-do-you-trigger-a-block-after-a-delay-like-performselectorwithobjectafter)

I think it shouldn't be a category.

Strange that I ended up using GCD.

However, using it is simple. I just do:

```
    [BGPerformDelayedBlock performSlightlyDelayedBlock:^{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
            [self snapToTheTopOfTheNonHeaderView];
        }];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is similar to, using a `NSTimer` setting a selector after 0.01sec with no repeats. This will be called on the main thread.

`NSOperation` or blocks are used to perform operations in background. These you can use instead of `performSelectorInBackground`.

If your need is to work in background then go for it. There are many tutorials available to learn 'NSOperation`using 'NSOperationQueue` and blocks.

Comment: I already use tons of NSOperationQueue. [NSOperationQueue MainQueue] addoperationwithblock, for example will sort of work too. But I need delay. I want solution with blocks rather than selector.