# Call back when the app is deleted form cache in iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6

I was wondering if there is a call back when the app is deleted form cache (press home key for 5 secs and then delete the app)?

I am using a NSTimer to pop up a message after few days. The timer does not call the method if the app is deleted form cache. I do not want to use [NSDate date] on device as it can be changed by user. I have also looked at [after_Delay()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139219/how-do-you-trigger-a-block-after-a-delay-like-performselectorwithobjectafter), but as far as I have tried, the block do not get executed if I delete the app from cache.

Th app is iPAD only.

Comment: No, when the app is removed from that list it is killed, no exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

> as far as I have tried, the block do not get executed if I delete the app from cache.

That's because you're killing the app. If you debug an app and kill it in the manner you describe, you'll notice that the debugger stops in `main()` and tells you that the app received a `SIGKILL` signal. If iOS sent a different signal, like `SIGTERM`, you could install a handler for the signal and use that to take some action. But `SIGKILL` kills your app immediately, and you can't install a handler for it, so you're out of luck.