# scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nstimer

i am trying to active scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval not in the main thread. 
this is my code.

```
-(void)setMidnightUpdate{

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 
                                            0), ^{

        if(midnightTimer && [midnightTimer isValid]) {
            [midnightTimer invalidate];
            midnightTimer = nil;
        } 

secs = 10;
midnightTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:secs 
                                                 target:self 
                                               selector:@selector(midnightUpdate) 
                                               userInfo:nil 
                                                repeats:NO];
```

});

```
-(void)midnightUpdate{

}
```

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSTimer *midnightTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:secs 
                                                          target:self 
                                                        selector:@selector(midnightUpdate)  
                                                        userInfo:nil 
                                                         repeats:YES];
[midnightTimer fire];
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible use:

dispatch_after
Enqueue a block for execution at the specified time.

```
void dispatch_after(
   dispatch_time_t when,
   dispatch_queue_t queue,
   dispatch_block_t block);
```

from another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4139331/451475):

```
// Delay execution of my block for 10 seconds.
dispatch_time_t futureTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
dispatch_after(futureTime, aQueue, ^{
    < midnightUpdate code>
});
```