# Is there any way to schedule local notification with different text on every day?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I want to schedule a local notification with a text like "Day 1" on first day and "Day 2" on second day like that:

```
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)


    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = // ex: 5 am
    notification.alertBody = "Day 1" // on second day it want to be "Day 2" , on third day it want to be "Day 3" like that..
    notification.alertAction = "be awesome!"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.userInfo = ["CustomField1": "w00t"]
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Is there any possibility to do this?

User will receive a notification of first Day as "Day 1"

Second Day as "Day 2"

Third Day as "Day 3"

Is it possible to set a notification like that?

Comment: Yes, you count it for a day long, then change the text.

Comment: Sorry, Unable to get What you said. Please Explain me...

Comment: I mean you have to count the time which long = 1 day. Then change the text.

Comment: Sorry.. How to count.. I didn't catch what you mean.. Where to count.. User may or may not open the app, even though the notification appear and more over user no need to open the app.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641761/run-timer-in-background-when-app-is-closed

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule notifications for whole week with something like this:

```
func scheduleAwesomeNotifications() {
    for day in 0...7 {
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

        let intervalForDay = Double(60 * 60 * 24 * day)

        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.fireDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(intervalForDay)
        notification.alertBody = "Day " + day.description
        notification.alertAction = "be awesome!"
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        notification.userInfo = ["CustomField1": "w00t"]
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You, Working fine... But for long days like a year or more.... How to do... if i use a for loop for an year Apple will allow this for publishing... for loop for one year is correct approach...

Comment: Use NSCalendar approach for that. With it you can add any value to a date http://stackoverflow.com/a/36696052/4108415.