# Instantiate a background runloop in iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

### Use Case

I have a set of processes that each need to run on their own background thread at a certain execution rate (3 times a second, once every 10 seconds etc).

I *believe* `CFRunLoop` and/or `NSRunLoop` provide this functionality

### Question

How do I create (in swift) a new background thread for which to execute a periodic tasks on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056205/how-to-use-background-thread-in-swift This question might help you

Comment: This answer has one-and-done processes not loops

Comment: Calling that with a NSTimer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951980/swift-do-something-every-x-minutes

Comment: @milo526 thanks for trying - but I'm looking specifically to start an independent background thread loop.  The timer just calls in whatever thread it was called from ... (i think).

Comment: The second answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25952724/2976077) does only run on a background thread. it first creates a new thread and run it every x seconds.

Comment: Anyone asking questions on stackoverflow shouldn't use CFRunLoop. And most people answering questions here don't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Old post but "background run loop" doesn't equal "background thread" nor does it mean "background queue". Usually there is only one run loop and that is the main thread's run loop. Other threads usually use this run loop but rarely have their own run loop (or their respective run loops are never readily available). To create a run loop for a thread that is not the main thread Apple has a [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW24) and states when this should be done.

Also [here](https://academy.realm.io/posts/realm-notifications-on-background-threads-with-swift/) is a nice guide I found on run loops in background threads.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with the Global Dispatch background queue.

Example background thread:

```
      let qualityServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
      let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityServiceClass, 0)

        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {  
            print("This is run on the background queue")
            // With the help of NSTimer it will hit method after every 5 minutes (300 seconds).
            _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(300.0, target: self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.callAppSettingWebservice), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        })
```

Comment: this isn't running on a run loop

Comment: I just create a background thread using GCD as asked by @Jeef in the above question to do a task in the background thread at a periodic interval.