# Update Once each in specific time

Tags: ios, swift

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
    parallax.update(currentTime)
}
```

How can i control the update to be done once over a specific period of time

Comment: Are you sure all those tags are applicable?

Comment: no. am a junior here. excuse me if sth is wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do something every x minutes in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25951980/2415822)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do something every x minutes in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951980/do-something-every-x-minutes-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't add much to your question, so I don't really know if this is what you are looking for, but here is some code to call a function every X time (swift 3):

```
// call MyMethod every 1 second :
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(MyController.myMethod), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Please search before you post a question -> [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951980/do-something-every-x-minutes-in-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Yes that solved the problem. Thank You

Comment: Ok you can set my answer as approved then, and you should modify your question so it's more clear

Comment: Instead of answering bad and duplicate questions, you should be flagging them as duplicates.

Comment: You're right I didn't check if it's duplicated