# How do I do something every n-th attempt?

Tags: swift

I have a game that is based on attempts rather than score. And I wish to display a pop up every 10 attempts. What is the best way, using Swift, to calculate every 10 intervals of something?

Currently I call a function to increment the attempts value which includes: `gamesPlayedSaved += 1`. The closest question I found on [here uses timers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951980/do-something-every-x-minutes-in-swift), which wouldn't work in my case.

So far, I have this (WHICH IS EXTREMELY UGLY):

```
if(gamesPlayedSaved == 10 ||
                    gamesPlayedSaved == 20 ||
                    gamesPlayedSaved == 30 ||
                    gamesPlayedSaved == 40 ||
                    gamesPlayedSaved == 50 ||
                    gamesPlayedSaved == 60 ||
                    gamesPlayedSaved == 70 ||
                    gamesPlayedSaved == 80 ||
                    gamesPlayedSaved == 90 ||
                    gamesPlayedSaved == 100){
    // call pop up
}
```

And it also doesn't account for any intervals over 100.

Comment: Google: swift 3 remainder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved using maths. You just need to decide whether `gamesPlayedSaved` is a multiple of 10. To do this, find the remainder of `gamesPlayedSaved / 10` using the modulo operator `%` and check if it is 0:

```
if gamesPlayedSaved % 10 == 0 && gamesPlayedSaved > 0 {
    // show pop up
}
```

Alternatively, reset the counter every time it reaches 10:

```
if gamesPlayedSaved == 10 {
    // show pop up
    gamesPlayedSaved = 0
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Prefect implementation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use modulus %. `if (gamesPlayedSaved % 10 == 0)`

It will finds the remainder after division of 10

Comment: Ah of course, I always forget modulus. Works great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

```
for i in 1...100 {
    if i % 10 == 0 {
        print("Yep: \(i)")
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Yep: 10
Yep: 20
Yep: 30
Yep: 40
Yep: 50
Yep: 60
Yep: 70
Yep: 80
Yep: 90
Yep: 100
```

The `%` operator is called *modulo*, it returns the remainder when dividing a number A with number B. In your case you are interested in the cases when the number of games played is divisible by 10, ie. `numberOfGamesPlayed % 10 == 0`.

Comment: This is really useful. I love it. Thank you.