# Do something every x minutes during application lifetime- Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

What i wanted to do is to check for updates in every 10 minutes by calling a webservice. But this should not effect the application main thread.

Also user should be able to interact with UI.

For single view controller [This SO Answer works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25952076/5215474)

I hope this should be a global timer running in background thread.

How can i create such a timer? having lifetime scope?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: have edited question. pls check @SalmanGhumsani

Comment: Write this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951980/do-something-every-x-minutes-in-swift/25952076#25952076 in Appdelegate it will calls until the app dies.

Comment: is this working in background thread?

Comment: Yes, It will call in background thread, and make sure your calling service also be in background thread

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do something every x minutes in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951980/do-something-every-x-minutes-in-swift)