# Do something every minute in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, xcode9, swift4

I am doing an iOS app using Swift 4 but I am struggling to find how to execute a certain amount of code every minute.

There is a timer in my app which calculate the difference between the starting time and the current time and I should update a label with the result every minute.

I think that I should use `scheduledTimer(timeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)` but I don't understand how should I implement it.

By trying with the answer of [Unheilig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25952076/7845320) with

```
var helloWorldTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.sayHello), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        func sayHello()
        {
            NSLog("hello World")
        }
```

I got the error **Type 'ViewController' has no member 'sayHello'**

Comment: The function `sayHello()` must be on the top level of the class.

Comment: For Swift 4, the method of which you want to get the selector must be exposed to Objective-C, thus @objc attribute must be added to the method declaration. e.g ``` @objc func sayHello(){} ```

Comment: @ShamimHossain Thank you! It works!