How to deallocate resource in main actor isolated object in deinit
I have a main actor isolated class like this one:
@MainActor
open class TimerScheduler {
  
  private enum TimerState {
    case normal
    case paused(remaining: TimeInterval)
  }
  
  private struct TimerInfo {
    let timer: Timer
    let state: TimerState
  }
  
  private var keyToTimerInfoMap = [String:TimerInfo]()
  private let lifecycleChecker: () -> Bool

  public init(lifecycleChecker: @escaping @MainActor () -> Bool = { true }) {
    
    self.lifecycleChecker = lifecycleChecker
    
    // Note: When app is in background, NSTimer will only get a few minutes of execution.
    // Then the timer will be paused
    // These notifications are there to ensure NSTimer is paused immediately when app goes background.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(pause), name:UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(resume), name:UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
  }
  
  deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    for (_, info) in keyToTimerInfoMap {
      info.timer.invalidate()
    }
  }

  private func unschedule(key: String) {
    guard let info = keyToTimerInfoMap[key] else { return }
    info.timer.invalidate()
    keyToTimerInfoMap.removeValue(forKey: key)
  }

  // other functions

}

I have a warning:

Cannot access property 'keyToTimerInfoMap' with a non-sendable type '[String : TimerScheduler.TimerInfo]' from non-isolated deinit; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode

This is reasonable because deinit can happen in any thread.
Xcode also suggests to convert TimerInfo Sendable, which I can't do because Timer is not Sendable.
I could wrap the deinit in a main actor Task like this:
  deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    Task { @MainActor in
      for (_, info) in keyToTimerInfoMap {
        info.timer.invalidate()
      }
    }
  }

However, if the object is deinit'ed in the background thread, I would be using the object (accessing its keyToTimerInfoMap field) after it's been deallocated, which seems to be a dangerous thing to do.
I am using Xcode 16 beta 3, Swift 5 with "complete" concurrency checking.

but deinit is part of the deallocation, isn't it?

My understanding is that it is not safe to use the object after deinit returns.

is it safer to capture keyToTimerInfoMap rather than self?

Will self.keyToTimerInfoMap be garbage or zeroed out after deinit?

@Paulw11 I just did some experiments and it appears that you are incorrect. When I try to make self outlive its deinit, I get a crash saying "This object's deinit, or something called from it, may have created a strong reference to self which outlived deinit, resulting in a dangling reference."

btw. if you use a Combine Timer publisher you'll probably find this problem is way simpler to solve. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/replacing-foundation-timers-with-timer-publishers

I used mainActor because lifecycleChecker needs to be run on main actor. I use lifecycleChecker to verify that the UI that holds this timer scheduler is still on screen, which requires main actor. I had a few crashes due to callback being called after the UI is already gone and this was the workaround

@Sweeper do you think it's safe to capture keyToTimerInfoMap?

Actually, i can't capture keyToTimerInfoMap, because TimerInfo is not sendable (it contains Timer object which is not sendable)

If you use this rendition of addObserver, the docs tell us “If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and later, you do not need to unregister an observer that you created with this function. If you forget or are unable to remove an observer, the system cleans up the next time it would have posted to it.” And if you use GCD timer rather than Timer, those timers will also be removed automatically for you when deallocated. The combination of those diminishes the need for deinit.

On the broader question of isolated deinit, it hasn’t made it into the language yet, but they’re obviously working on it. See discussion on SE-0317. IMHO, the lack of an isolated deinit greatly diminishes the whole value of a deinit method, at all.

@Rob by "GCD timer" do you mean dispatch_after?

No, I was talking about a DispatchSourceTimer, as created by makeTimerSource(flags:queue:). E.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/25952724/1271826.

Since keyToTimerInfoMap is a private property, which means, when deinit is executing it can't be mutated from other place (thread/actor). We should be able to safely make the cleanup.
And to disable static checking of data isolation we can use nonisolated(unsafe) property attribute introduced in Swift 5.10:
  nonisolated(unsafe)
  private var keyToTimerInfoMap = [String: TimerInfo]()

P.S. I'm not super expert in this topic. So, if I'm wrong - please don't hesitate to comment about what's wrong 

Do you think even if it's a  public property, it's still safe to make deinit nonisolated(unsafe)? Because we are not supposed to access the object after deinit returns anyways? (From Sweeper's comment, "This object's deinit, or something called from it, may have created a strong reference to self which outlived deinit, resulting in a dangling reference.")

IMHO, it is unsafe too make it public, because it is possible to mutate from outside (not because object was deinitialised). But if it is public private(set) must be safe

Long story short is that you can't. If you need something to be deallocated on the Main Actor you need to introduce a explicit @MainActor func stop() and call that before your object is deallocated by its owner (this can be necessary if you're wrapping things like the AVPlayer).
A better solution is to avoid having Main Actor isolated properties/objects that needs to be explicitly deallocated, like Silmaril suggested.
Consider not marking your entire class @MainActor as well, and only use it for the relevant (public) properties. There's really nothing in the code you shown us that requires use of MainActor.

it's very inconvenient to call stop() for every scheduler because this is part of the library that I wrote and I would have to update all my apps that use this library :(

@OMGPOP that's why I suggested you use Combine timers

The thing is that my app is not necessarily SwiftUI. The consumer can either be SwiftUI or SpriteKit apps

@OMGPOP Combine timers have nothing to do with SwiftUI. It just gets you a Set of AnyCancellable that'll release the times when deallocated.

GCD timers work pretty much the same: when they fall out of scope, they will be canceled. Timer is added to the runloop and you have to manually invalidate. Combine and GCD timers don’t rely on runloops.
