# UIViewAnimation from dispatch_after blocking UIViewAnimation Completion block

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, uiviewanimation

I have following scenario :

```
dispatch_after_delta(0.1, ^{
    [self checkForTodaysBonus];  // It contains animation methods.
});
```

And

```
-(void) checkForTodaysBonus {
     // Prepare View and other data and then animate UIView
     [Animations moveDown:self.view andAnimationDuration:0.3 andWait:YES andLength:self.view.frame.size.height];
}
```

where, moveDown method is like :

```
+ (void) moveDown: (UIView *)view andAnimationDuration: (float) duration andWait:(BOOL) wait andLength:(float) length{
    __block BOOL done = wait; //wait =  YES wait to finish animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        view.center = CGPointMake(view.center.x, view.center.y + length);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         // This never happens if I call this method from dispatch_after. 
         done = NO;
    }];
    // wait for animation to finish
    // This loop will allow wait to complete animation
      while (done == YES) {  // Application unable to break this condition
         [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];
       }
}
```

And

```
 void dispatch_after_delta(float delta, dispatch_block_t block){
       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delta * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
 }
```

So, **issue**, whenever `animation` method is called from `dispatch_after_delta`, `animation` method `never gets its completion block`.

What could be possible solution ?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139219/how-do-you-trigger-a-block-after-a-delay-like-performselectorwithobjectafter

Comment: @SergeyNikitin : Please check, thats what I am doing. I am using dispatch_after_delay. Main issue is UIViewAnimation is not getting completion method.

Answer (score 0):

My advice to you would be to use `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:`.

Replace your current dispatch_after with:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(checkForTodaysBonus) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
```

Comment: Yes, thats good thing, but at some places, I have to create different method to use performSelector..so I am looking for solution with dispatch_after

Answer (score 0):

Than's because you submit the block

```
^{
   [self checkForTodaysBonus];  // It contains animation methods.
});
```

to the main queue,and  main queue is a serial queue,so the animation completion block won't execute until the block above return.

To solve this issue,you can :

1. submit the block to the global queue

   `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delta * NSEC_PER_SEC),
     dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), block);`
2. execute the animation in the main queue :

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
       view.center = CGPointMake(view.center.x, view.center.y + length);

   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       // This never happens if I call this method from dispatch_after.
       done = NO;
   }];
   ```

   });

In my opinion,you'd better not to use NSThread and NSRunLoop explicitly in the dispatch block.