# NSTimer? - Check Connection iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

I am using the following method to check if my app has a connection. It's simple and works great for my needs.

```
+ (void)checkInternet:(connection)block
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"HEAD";
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
    request.timeoutInterval = 10.0;

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:
     ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         block([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode] == 200);
     }];
}
```

However, what I'd like to do is if the status doesn't return 200, I'd like to check again, at least a couple of times. What's the best way to do this with 1 second intervals?

Below is how I'm calling the above method.

```
 [self checkInternet:^(BOOL internet)
    {
         if (internet)
         {
             // "Internet" aka Google
         }
         else
         {
             // No "Internet" aka no Google
         }
    }];
```

Comment: Why are you checking at all?

Comment: Why not use Reachability class?

Comment: Check Internet connectivity only when you are hitting web service It may save your battery life.

Comment: There are things that do this for you. Check out the Reachability class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) for detecting general network connection issues (See end of answer). I use the following method for executing retries.

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;
```

You could adapt your system something like the following to have a new class method which has an optional number of retries.

NB. Not tested the following. It is just to give you the general idea.

```
// Variable to track number of retries left. If you had a shared instance
// a property would be easier.
static NSUInteger maxConnectionTries = 0;

// New method which lets you pass a retry count.
+ (void)checkInternet:(connection)block withMaxTries:(NSUInteger)maxTries
{
   maxConnectionTries=maxTries;
   [self checkInternet:block];
}

// Your original code extended to retry by calling itself when code 200
// is seen on a delay of 1s. Defaults to old code when retry limit exceeded
// or non 200 code received.
+ (void)checkInternet:(connection)block
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"HEAD";
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
    request.timeoutInterval = 10.0;

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:
     ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if ([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode] != 200 &&
             maxConnectionRetries > 0){
           maxConnectionRetries--;
           [self performSelector:@selector(checkInternet:) withObject:block afterDelay:1.0]; 
         }
         else{
           maxConnectionRetries = 0;
           block([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode] == 200);
         }
     }];
}
```

For general detection of internet connectivity, it is best to use Reachability. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

I start a reachability handler from my AppDelegate code and then publish local notifications when connectivity changes occur. This allows the application to always receive connection change notification and transient view controllers within `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` to register and deregister for local notifications if they are interested in connection changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help here this makes sense! Just to be clear in the If/Else logic, I'd want to retry only if the response code != 200

Comment: Ah, I got that wrong. Updated answer so its when != 200

Comment: Correct, I was just saying looking at your code example it's coded that way :)

Comment: Hey Rory, this is working awesome! However, is it possible to write the "performSelector" so that it just calls right back into the WithRetries method? I've tried something like this   [self performSelector:@selector(checkInternet:withMaxTries:) withObject:block withObject: tries afterDelay:1.0];

Comment: The trouble is needing two parameters. You could use `dispatch_after` instead which lets you dispatch a block of code after a period. In here you could the call the withRetries method. See example here on how to dispatch a block with a delay: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139219/how-do-you-trigger-a-block-after-a-delay-like-performselectorwithobjectafter

Answer (score 0):

FYI here is what I came up with:

```
+ (void)checkInternet:(connection)block withMaxTries:(NSUInteger)maxTries
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"HEAD";
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
    request.timeoutInterval = 10.0;

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:
     ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if ([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode] != 200 &&
             maxTries > 0){

             dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                 [self checkInternet:block withMaxTries:maxTries - 1];
             });
        }
         else{
             block([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode] == 200);
         }
     }];
}
```