# How to delay load specific content of UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I implemented a calendar view with `UICollectionView`, when scrolling the calendar view very fast, it's not smooth. So I'm thinking whether I can load static content of each cell firstly, and then refresh once specific content has been loaded. So how to delay loading specific contents of each `UICollectionViewCell`

Specifically, in below function, I'll construct each `UICollectionViewCell` and return it. Now I just want to construct static contents (such as the date), and delay loading specific contents (such as the background color, if I have an event this day, I'll change the background of this cell), so where should I load specific contents, and how to only refresh showing cell

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:UICollectionViewCellIdentifier
                                                                                     forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDate *date = [self dateAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.dateLabel.text = [date description];

    // This is the part I want to delay, since it's cost.
    if (dataModel.hasEventAtDate(date)) {
        cell.dateLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blue];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you show more what do you want to delay load? For the delay, you can use dispatch_after

Comment: thanks, i just updated my question, please check out the latest version

Comment: Can you show inside of `cellForItemAtIndexPath`?

Comment: @anhtu updated again, thanks for your quick response:)

Comment: You can try to use dispatch_after. But I think it still isn't smooth. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139219/how-do-you-trigger-a-block-after-a-delay-like-performselectorwithobjectafter

Answer (score 0):

You may need have an instance variable to track if cells need to update:

```
Boolean cellNeedsUpdate = NO
```

In cellForItemAtIndexPath, check if you need to fully update the cells:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (cellNeedsUpdate) {
        // fully update the cell
    } else {
        // do partial update
    }
}
```

Track end scrolling of the collectionView, then reload the collectionView:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    cellNeesUpdate = !cellNeedsUpdate;
    [collectionView reloadData];
}
```