# Wait/Delay in Xcode (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, delay

How do i add a delay in Xcode?

```
self.label1.alpha = 1.0
//delay
self.label1.alpha = 0.0
```

I'd like to make it wait about 2 seconds. I've read about time_dispatch and importing the darwin library, but i haven't been able to make it work. So can someone please explain it properly step by step?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you trigger a block after a delay, like -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139219/how-do-you-trigger-a-block-after-a-delay-like-performselectorwithobjectafter)

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/2538939

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only have to write this code:

```
self.label1.alpha = 1.0    

let delay = 2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // After 2 seconds this line will be executed            
    self.label1.alpha = 0.0
}
```

'2' is the seconds you want to wait

Regards

Answer (score 5):

This is another option that works -

`import Darwin
 sleep(2)`

Then, you can use the sleep function, which takes a number of seconds as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, BK15. For what it's worth, I didn't need to import Darwin because I'm already importing Foundation. I'm using Swift 3, iOS 10, and Xcode 8.

Comment: This is so much better than a duplicate answer (for a duplicate question) I found that uses an asynchronous dispatch queue function (which didn't work in some settings).

Answer (score 3):

Might be better to use blocks for this one:

```
self.label1.alpha = 1.0;

UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^(void) {
    self.label1.alpha = 0.0;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5:

```
self.label1.alpha = 1.0 

let delay : Double = 2.0 //delay time in seconds
let time = DispatchTime.now() + delay
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:time){
    // After 2 seconds this line will be executed
    self.label1.alpha = 0.0
}
```

This works for me.

Referring to: [Delay using DispatchTime.now() + float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48021298/delay-using-dispatchtime-now-float)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend for production, but does the trick

```
import Foundation 
func block(for t: Double) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    let _ = group.wait(timeout: .now() + t)
}
```