# YALFoldingTabBarController change centerButtonImage depending on selected ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm using YALFoldingTabBar for a project https://github.com/Yalantis/FoldingTabBar.iOS

I want to change its behavior a bit, by showing the current ViewController as the centerButtonImage, instead of a plus/cross sign.

I've tried to override `didSelectItem` like this:

```
   override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {

    switch(self.selectedIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        self.centerButtonImage = UIImage(named: "whatever")
    default:
        //Change image
    }

    switch (self.selectedViewController)
    {
    case 0 as GameViewController:
        //Change image
    default:
        //Change image
    }
}
```

The code below is in my `CustomTabBar`, subclassing `YALFoldingTabBarController`.

But it doesn't seem to work that way. I've also tried to manipulate the tabBar in the specific `UIViewControllers`'s `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` but it seems like the tabBar is set only.

Is this possible, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: It seems like the method is not called, when changing viewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got `didSelectItem` to work, and neither the `UITabBarControllerDelegate`´s equivalent. However, YALFoldingTabBar have delegate methods `tabBarViewWillExpand` and `tabBarViewWillCollapse` and I used these along with `tabBarView.layoutSubviews()` to solve my problem. It's not very beautiful, but works as intended.

```
func tabBarViewWillExpand(tabBarView: YALFoldingTabBar!) {

    self.centerButtonImage = UIImage(named: "plus_icon")
    //Helper method from other thread, link below
    performBlock({ () -> Void in
        tabBarView.layoutSubviews()
    }, afterDelay: 0.25)
}
```

[How do you trigger a block after a delay, like -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139219/how-do-you-trigger-a-block-after-a-delay-like-performselectorwithobjectafter)