# how to dispatch async block after X seconds from non-ui thread to the ui? using swift

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

From a non-view controller class I want to pop up to the ui a custom like- toast message.

I want it to appear for 2 seconds.

I know I need to use `dispatch_async` twice.
One for unhiding the message
Second for hiding the message after 2 seconds. This requires `dispatch_after()`?

How do I call the main view-controller from a different class? calling `self.showError()` will not work, because self is not the main view-controller.

I have tried this:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.showError()
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ??? 2 seconds) {
        self.hideError()
    }
```

Comment: yes, you want `dispatch_after`. It performs blocks asynchronously after a given time period. Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139219/how-do-you-trigger-a-block-after-a-delay-like-performselectorwithobjectafter?rq=1

Comment: thanks. jsut saw it's async as well. How do I call the main view-controller from a different class? calling `self.foo()` will not work

Comment: well you need a reference to the main view controller. If it's the `rootViewController`, you can access it through the `AppDelegate`, or you can setup your own delegate for this.

Comment: Thanks! not sure how to `setup your own delegate for this` will look into it