# How is that possible to post notification after 1 second delay or in a dispatch asyn?

Tags: swift, notifications

i just want to call a method after loading my view. i have set notification to one view and postnotification to other view you will get more idea from my code.. here is my code..

in a one.swift file

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "InsertNote:", name: "insert", object: nil)

        }

func InsertNote(notification:NSNotification)
     {
    println("blablalbla")
 }
```

in a second.swift file

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("getData"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    func getData()
    {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("insert", object: nil)
}
```

i have try also in a dispatch_asynch but still it is not work.

Comment: use dispatch_after instead of a NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval

Comment: not working i have tried both..

Comment: you can  async to global_queue then do it see more here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139219/how-do-you-trigger-a-block-after-a-delay-like-performselectorwithobjectafter/4139331#4139331

Comment: What does `getData()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let delayInSeconds: Double = 1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("insert", object: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: He mentioned async not working in a comment on his question. I'm guessing the first VC isn't around to receive the notification.

Comment: no this is not working... if you take a "dispatch_get_global_queue" then it works only in A viewcontroller not in current viewcontroller (B.V.)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can come up with that this doesn't work, is that your first ViewController A is already deallocated when you send the notification with the second ViewController B. So, you are sending the notification with B correctly, but A isn't around to receive it.

You can test this by adding an observer in B as well.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("getData"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "insertNote:", name: "insert", object: nil)
}

func getData() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("insert", object: nil)
}

func insertNote:(note: NSNotification) {
    print("Banana")
}

// Should print 'Banana' after one second.
```

Comment: i just want to call A viewcontroller method.. because i have so much data in A viewcontroller...

Comment: You should extract all that data and pass it to ViewController B in a simple data object when you present B. A view controller should not ask another view controller for relevant data as a matter of best practices.

Comment: Thank you spacyRicochet.. :)