# How to set delay before taking a picture by iphone camera?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, sdk

How to set delay before taking a picture by iphone camera? I use UIImagePickerController. Is there some simple way for it?

Comment: See also ["Blocks instead of performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007023/blocks-instead-of-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call a method with your "take the pic" after a delay, try this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethodToTakeThePhoto) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.5];


-(void)myMethodToTakeThePhoto{
// take the photo
}
```