# Write code instead of selector in like NSTimers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

Is there anyway to write code instead of setting a selector to method to call in NSTimer?
If i want to print hello world after 5 sec i can do it like this.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(helloWorld:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

and have this function

```
-(void)helloWorld:(NSTimer*)aTimer {
    NSLog(@"Hello World!");
}
```

But instead of writeing functions for every timer you have is it possible to add NSLog(@"Hello World!") in the same line as where i create the timer?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007023/blocks-instead-of-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay where you might find a suitable answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this code– an NSTimer category:

https://gist.github.com/250662/d4f99aa9bde841107622c5a239e0fc6fa37cb179

Answer (score 2):

Some methods allow you to pass a code block as a parameter.  Unfortunately this isn't supported for `NSTimer`.