# How do you schedule a block to run on the next run loop iteration?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch, nsrunloop

I want to be able to execute a `block` on the next run loop iteration. It's not so important whether it gets executed at the beginning or the end of the next run loop, just that execution is deferred until all code in the current run loop has finished executing.

I know the following doesn't work because it gets interleaved with the main run loop so my code might execute on the next run loop but it might not.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    //my code
});
```

The following I believe suffers the same problem as above:

```
dispatch_after(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //my code
});
```

Now I *believe* the following would work as it is placed at the end of the current run loop (correct me if I'm wrong), would this actually work?

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

What about a timer with a `0` interval? The documentation states: `If seconds is less than or equal to 0.0, this method chooses the nonnegative value of 0.1 milliseconds instead.` Does this translate to guaranteeing execution on the next run loop iteration?

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(myMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

That's all the options I can think of but I'm still no closer to executing a block (as opposed to calling a method) on the next run loop iteration with the guarantee that it won't be any sooner.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You might not be aware of everything that the run loop does in each iteration. (I wasn't before I researched this answer!) As it happens, `CFRunLoop` is part of the [open-source CoreFoundation package](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.12/), so we can take a look at exactly what it entails.  The run loop looks roughly like this:

```
while (true) {
    Call kCFRunLoopBeforeTimers observer callbacks;
    Call kCFRunLoopBeforeSources observer callbacks;
    Perform blocks queued by CFRunLoopPerformBlock;
    Call the callback of each version 0 CFRunLoopSource that has been signalled;
    if (any version 0 source callbacks were called) {
        Perform blocks newly queued by CFRunLoopPerformBlock;
    }
    if (I didn't drain the main queue on the last iteration
        AND the main queue has any blocks waiting)
    {
        while (main queue has blocks) {
            perform the next block on the main queue
        }
    } else {
        Call kCFRunLoopBeforeWaiting observer callbacks;
        Wait for a CFRunLoopSource to be signalled
          OR for a timer to fire
          OR for a block to be added to the main queue;
        Call kCFRunLoopAfterWaiting observer callbacks;
        if (the event was a timer) {
            call CFRunLoopTimer callbacks for timers that should have fired by now
        } else if (event was a block arriving on the main queue) {
            while (main queue has blocks) {
                perform the next block on the main queue
            }
        } else {
            look up the version 1 CFRunLoopSource for the event
            if (I found a version 1 source) {
                call the source's callback
            }
        }
    }
    Perform blocks queued by CFRunLoopPerformBlock;
}
```

You can see that there are a variety of ways to hook into the run loop.  You can create a `CFRunLoopObserver` to be called for any of the “activities” you want.  You can create a version 0 `CFRunLoopSource` and signal it immediately.  You can create a connected pair of `CFMessagePorts`, wrap one in a version 1 `CFRunLoopSource`, and send it a message.  You can create a `CFRunLoopTimer`.  You can queue blocks using either `dispatch_get_main_queue` or `CFRunLoopPerformBlock`.

You will need to decide which of these APIs to use based on when you are scheduling the block, and when you need it to be called.

For example, touches are handled in a version 1 source, but if you handle the touch by updating the screen, that update isn't actually performed until the Core Animation transaction is committed, which happens in a `kCFRunLoopBeforeWaiting` observer.

Now suppose you want to schedule the block while you're handling the touch, but you want it to be executed after the transaction is committed.

You can add your own `CFRunLoopObserver` for the `kCFRunLoopBeforeWaiting` activity, but this observer might run before or after Core Animation's observer, depending on the order you specify and the order Core Animation specifies.  (Core Animation currently specifies an order of 2000000, but that is not documented so it could change.)

To make sure your block runs after Core Animation's observer, even if your observer runs *before* Core Animation's observer, don't call the block directly in your observer's callback.  Instead, use `dispatch_async` at that point to add the block to the main queue.  Putting the block on the main queue will force the run loop to wake up from its “wait” immediately.  It will run any `kCFRunLoopAfterWaiting` observers, and then it will drain the main queue, at which time it will run your block.

Comment: This is a great summary of what a run loop does. For the OP's question, I'd say that `CFRunLoopPerformBlock()` would be the most kosher way to make sure that the block executes on the next loop of the run loop. The docs don't explicitly state that the block won't be executed if it's added in the middle of a loop, but they do say: "This method enqueues the block only and does not automatically wake up the specified run loop. Therefore, execution of the block occurs the next time the run loop wakes up to handle another input source." You could check by adding the block in an observer callback.

Comment: Hi @rob mayor, this is an very old great answer, but : touches are not handled in a version 0 source instead ? When I add a break point in a method like `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`, the stack shows « CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION_ ». 
I don’t really distinguish between source0 and source1 … Even after reading https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html

Comment: It's possible that Apple changed how touches are handled, or that they are handled differently on the simulator than on a device. I don't have time to investigate right now.

Comment: In `CFRunLoopMain.c` the only place `didDispatchPortLastTime` is used is: `if (dispatchPort != MACH_PORT_NULL && !didDispatchPortLastTime)` which, if true, **waits for a message** using `__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort`. This makes me think that saying "if (I didn't drain the main queue on the last iteration AND the main queue has any blocks waiting) then (drain the main queue)" might not be accurate as it doesn't drain the main queue but rather waits for a message. Am I right in this or have I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

Rob answer is great and informative. I'm not trying to replace it.

Just reading the [UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animatewithduration?language=objc), I found :

> **completion**
>
> A block object to be executed when the animation sequence
> ends. This block has no return value and takes a single Boolean
> argument that indicates whether or not the animations actually
> finished before the completion handler was called. If the duration of
> the animation is 0, this block is performed at the beginning of the
> next run loop cycle. This parameter may be NULL.

So an easy solution would be:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: {}) { _ in
    // anything
}
```

Comment: Code snippet is wrong. the documentation is for the `completion` callback, and not `animations` callback... the correct solution would be: `UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: {}) { //anything }`

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is any API that will allow you to guarantee code gets run on the very next event loop turn.  I'm also curious why you need a guarantee that nothing else has run on the loop, the main one in particular.

I can also confirm that using the perforSelector:withObject:afterDelay does use a runloop-based timer, and will have functionally similar behavior to dispatch_async'ing on dispatch_get_main_queue().

edit:

Actually, after re-reading your question, it sounds like you only need the *current* runloop turn to complete.  If that is true, then dispatch_async is exactly what you need.  In fact, all of the code above does make the guarantee that the *current* runloop turn will complete.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. The doc states: `The main dispatch queue is a globally available serial queue that executes tasks on the application’s main thread. This queue works with the application’s run loop (if one is present) to interleave the execution of queued tasks with the execution of other event sources attached to the run loop.` See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW2

Comment: One reason one may want to schedule a block to execute after the run loop cycle on which it was queued is to guarantee an ordered sequence of events. Creating a transaction or adding a series of otherwise unrelated transactions demands consideration of sequence. A run-loop cycle is a transaction. Where sequence is important, it is an inextricable element of consideration. At the time this question was asked, it may not have been perceived as a common need; today, an entire programming paradigm is based on just that: see Chapter 1 of Functional Reactive Programming (www.manning.com).

Answer (score -2):

dispatch_async on mainQueue is a good suggestion but it does not run on the next run loop it is inserted into the current run in the loop.

To get the behavior you are after you will need to resort to the traditional way:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

This also gives the added advantage is it can be canceled using NSObject's cancelPreviousPerforms.

Answer (score -3):

I wrote myself an [NSObject category](https://github.com/gradha/ELHASO-iOS-snippets/blob/master/src/NSObject%2BELHASO.m) which accepts a variable delay value, based on [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007023/blocks-instead-of-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay). By passing a value of zero you are effectively making the code run on the next available runloop iteration.