# UIView is shown after IBAction method returns

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've got the following code fragment (for illustration purpose):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender {
    UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    activityIndicator.center = overlayView.center;
    [overlayView addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:overlayView];
    //[self.navigationController.view bringSubviewToFront:overlayView];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    sleep(10);

    //[overlayView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I wonder why the overlay view is only displayed after the method returns...

Comment: from where returns

Comment: @MikeAlter from the stack :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's because `sleep(10)` blocks the main thread which is responsible for performing UI related activities, such as drawing on screen.

Remove the `sleep(10)` line and should work fine.

Here's on link to SO in case you're interested how to use delays in coca-touch:
[Adding delay between execution of two following lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335649/adding-delay-between-execution-of-two-following-lines)

Comment: Right... Then it's a bad idea to use synchronous operations within the method.