# Is it safe to pass an Objective-C block to performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, nsobject

I want to pass a block argument to `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.
For example, consider this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(delayedBlock:) withObject:^{
    // some code in block
} afterDelay:2];

- (void)delayedBlock:(void (^)(void))code {
    code();
}
```

It works but I am not sure if I need to do something special because of ARC.

Comment: Why not replace all of this will a call to `dispatch_after`? It's cleaner and you don't need the extra method.

Comment: Check the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007023/blocks-instead-of-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay

Answer (score 0):

As rmaddy wrote in the comment, there are better ways to perform a block with a delay, but if you want to use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, you should copy the block.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(delayedBlock:) withObject:[^{
    // some code in block
} copy] afterDelay:2];
```

From [Blocks Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html):

> Typically, you shouldn’t need to copy (or retain) a block. You only need to make a copy when you expect the block to be used after destruction of the scope within which it was declared. Copying moves a block to the heap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`GCD`** directly:

Here's a simple technique, based on GCD, that I'm using:

```
void RunBlockAfterDelay(NSTimeInterval delay, void (^block)(void))
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC*delay),
      dispatch_get_current_queue(), block);
}
```

Or use this useful **category**:

```
@implementation NSObject (PerformBlockAfterDelay)


- (void)performBlock:(void (^)(void))block 
          afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay 
{
    block = [block copy];

    [self performSelector:@selector(fireBlockAfterDelay:) 
               withObject:block 
               afterDelay:delay];
}

- (void)fireBlockAfterDelay:(void (^)(void))block
{
    block();
}

@end
```

Check out the discussion in this thread:
[Blocks instead of performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007023/blocks-instead-of-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay)

Comment: One disadvantage is dispatch_after is not cancellable. PerformSelector is cancellable with cancelPerformSelector.